# How to configure Kate to always use 2 spaces for tabulation?

Tags: kate, indentation, tabulation

By default Kate inserts 2 spaces on Tab press but switches to real tabs starting from the fourth Tab level. Can I disable this and use spaces always, regardless to the depth?

I want this because I use Kate to code Scala, and using space pairs instead of tabs is a convention there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click the Settings menu
2. Click "Configure - Kate"
3. On the right expand "Editor"
4. Click "Indentation"
5. Uncheck "Use spaces instead of tabs to indent".

That works with Kate 2.5.10 (Using KDE 3.5.10) on Debian.

Comment: I use Kate 3.5.1 of KDE 4.5.1 with Gnome 2.32.0 and could find nothing of like this on the "Indentation" tab of its settings window. :-(

Answer (score 1):

In 3.3.5:

1. Click Settings menu.
2. Click "Configure - Kate"
3. Expand "Editor Component"
4. Click "Editing"
5. Click on "Indentation" tab on the right
6. Change your Indentation width.